# Change location of file in VS Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Does anyone know how to change the location of a file from within Solution Explorer?

I have a file listed in Visual Studio 2013 under the Solution Explorer view. I have moved the file using Explorer. Now I want to change the location of the file in Solution Explorer. I know I can remove it and then add it again but long ago I found a way to change the location without remove/add. In properties I can see the old location but I can't type into that field.

Comment: If you moved the file in Windows Explorer, in VS you should see that the file was removed. You should delete the file, then click "show all files", then look in the new location, right click and select "include in project"

Comment: The file did not get removed in VS. I know I can delete and add but what I'm looking for is how just change the location. I have done it in the past ... I think with VS 2008 and I think I used a combo key to bring up the properties where I could make the change.

Comment: l19, I'm trying to run your procedure, If I delete the file using VS after I have moved it in Windows Explorer then it is simply removed from VS.  After it is removed from VS then I have to do another add which defeats the question. So maybe I don't understand your instructions. BTW, where is "show all files"?

Comment: I did some experimenting. In some cases alt/enter will bring up properties that can be changed but in other cases the properties can't be changed. I'm confused.

Comment: This seems to be a bug in VS. Using Alt/Enter, sometimes the "relative path" does not show up. I have not been able to figure out the circumstance.